# How to implement a feature that sorts a users list by followers count in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Need some suggestions. We added a follow feature in our app. We used the models and table structure of this tutorial - http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/09/how-to-create-a-user-followingfollower-system-like-twitter-in-laravel-4/

We added a following page that basically lists the usernames of the users that a user is following. Now the problem is we need to add a feature to sort the list by followers count. What's the simplest way that you can think of to add that feature? Without caching (like storing the followers count in the users table) if possible and still make the ->paginate() feature of Laravel work. I'd like to use caching only if this is not possible using a simple Eloquent query.

I've run out of ideas on how to construct the Eloquent query for it.

We're using Laravel 5.1 by the way.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show list of followings based on the count of it.

```
$topUsersJoinQuery = DB::table('user_follows')
            ->select('follow_id', DB::raw('COUNT(follow_id) AS count'))
            ->groupBy('follow_id'); //this will fetch the followers ids and group them.

$top_users = DB::table('users')->select('*')
            ->join(DB::raw('(' . $topUsersJoinQuery->toSql() . ') i'), function ($join)
            {
                $join->on('i.follow_id', '=', 'users.id');
            })
            ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
            ->select('name','id','title')
            ->take(3)
            ->get(); //joining the user_follows table with users table to fetech users info for view.blade.php
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a query like this:

```
select 
users.*, followerTempTable.followers_count 
from users 
left join (
    select user_id, count(*) as followers_count from followers group by user_id
) as followerTempTable on followerTempTable.user_id = users.id 
order by followers_count
-- add your limit and offset conditions for pagination
```

This link might be useful also: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: Thanks Arjon, do you have an Eloquent version of that query?